# Does editable=false apply at the database level?

Tags: django, django-models

When fields are set to `editable=False`, the docs say:

> If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is True.

Are any restrictions placed on the database itself, or is this simply restrictions on the client side?

If not, is there a way to enforce this integrity of non-editable fields at the database level?

Comment: No, `editable` is only something for the forms. To the best of my knowledge, there is no general way in SQL to make a row non-editable (some databases might have a dialect to do that, or you can create a "trigger" that rejects all changes), but it is definitely not something that is common at databases.

Comment: Also not sure why you'd want this at the database level... making a field non-editable at database level is equivalent to saying "create a column that is always empty and can never have any values in it".

Comment: > Also not sure why you'd want this at the database level...
I think it means more that it's only settable on row creation, and after that the value is frozen, which might have its uses.